# Python: Improving performance - Writing to database in seperate thread

Tags: python, mysql, python-multithreading, mysql-python

I am running a python app where I for various reasons have to host my program on a server in one part of the world and then have my database in another.

I tested via a simple script, and from my home which is in a neighboring country to the database server, the time to write and retrieve a row from the database is about 0.035 seconds (which is a nice speed imo) compared to 0,16 seconds when my python server in the other end of the world performs same action.
This is an issue as I am trying to keep my python app as fast as possible so I was wondering if there is a smart way to do this?

As I am running my code synchronously my program is waiting every time it has to write to the db, which is about 3 times a second so the time adds up. Is it possible to run the connection to the database in a separate thread or something, so it doesn't halt the whole program while it tries to send data to the database? Or can this be done using asyncio (I have no experience with async code)?

I am really struggling figuring out a good way to solve this issue.
In advance, many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create a thread that does the writes in the background. In your case, it seems reasonable to have a queue where the main thread puts things to be written and the db thread gets and writes them. The queue can have a maximum depth so that when too much stuff is pending, the main thread waits. You could also do something different like drop things that happen too fast. Or, use a db with synchronization and write a local copy. You also may have an opportunity to speed up the writes a bit by committing multiple at once.

This is a sketch of a worker thread

```
import threading
import queue

class SqlWriterThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, db_connect_info, maxsize=8):
        super().__init__()
        self.db_connect_info = db_connect_info
        self.q = queue.Queue(maxsize)
        # TODO: Can expose q.put directly if you don't need to
        # intercept the call
        # self.put = q.put
        self.start()

    def put(self, statement):
        print(f"DEBUG: Putting\n{statement}")
        self.q.put(statement)

    def run(self):
        db_conn = None
        while True:
            # get all the statements you can, waiting on first
            statements = [self.q.get()]
            try:
                while True:
                    statements.append(self.q.get(), block=False)
            except queue.Empty:
                pass
            try:
                # early exit before connecting if channel is closed.
                if statements[0] is None:
                    return
                if not db_conn:
                    db_conn = do_my_sql_connect()
                try:
                    print("Debug: Executing\n", "--------\n".join(f"{id(s)} {s}" for s in statements))
                    # todo: need to detect closed connection, then reconnect and resart loop
                    cursor = db_conn.cursor()
                    for statement in statements:
                        if statement is None:
                            return
                        cursor.execute(*statement)
                finally:
                    cursor.commit()       
            finally:
                for _ in statements:
                    self.q.task_done()

sql_writer = SqlWriterThread(('user', 'host', 'credentials'))
sql_writer.put(('execute some stuff',))
```

Comment: So I tried implementing this into my code but I am experiencing a weird issue and I have a question about your code. In your example above you have a sql_q variable, but you never assign or reference to it. Where is this coming from? Or is it a mistake where it should have been self.q instead?
I tried implementing the code using self.q, but it seems that every time I call sql_writer.put and add a new statement to the que, all the statements end up being copies of each other, even though I definitely am inputting different statements.

Comment: I just did some testing and figured out this is caused by my program adding to the queue within 2 seconds. If I time.sleep(2) the queue items stay true to what they are, but if I .put within a interval of 2 seconds all the items in the queue become copies of each other. How can I solve this, as waiting 2 seconds defeats the whole point of having this queue system.

Comment: Yes, that should be `self.q`. I originally wrote it as functions and changed it to a class - and injected bugs in the process. Like a two for one offer. Looking at second issue.

Comment: I couldn't spot a reason for the duplicate puts so added some debug to the mix.

Comment: Nice, well I fixed my issue, so I thank you many times for the nice example. I had never heard of python queue before, but it seems genius and I will definitely be using it a lot in the future. Have a nice weekend!